# Extracting integer and float numbers

Tags: string, numbers

I have the following string "10P_57.53%_568AA". I want to extract only numbers (integer and float numbers)  without any other things. The output should be like this:
10 57.53 568

Comment: Are you planning to use a programming language to do this? If so, please edit your question to tell us which one, and add the appropriate tag for the language.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not provided any language, this would be general  method:

Run a loop, get each character of string in a variable say X. Compare X as if(X>=0||X<=9||X=='.'){ Concat value of X to some string }

Comment: var str="10P_57.53%_568AA";
var X,Y;
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  X=str[i];
if(X>=0||X<=9||X=='.'){ 
 Y=Y+X;
}
}